# Virtual mouse driver, possible problems with X11

Tags: drivers, kernel, xorg, mouse

I created virtual mouse driver according to [Essential Linux Device Drivers](http://www.embeddedlinux.org.cn/EssentialLinuxDeviceDrivers/final/ch07lev1sec1.html) book. After i wrote coordinates **echo x y > /sys/ ... /coordinates** into sysfs node, my program generates event packets through event interface **/dev/input/event5** (i checked this). This event interface is attached to the GPM **gpm -m /dev/input/event5 -t evdev**. But mouse don't move.
  [I asked this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482260/using-linux-virtual-mouse-driver)
and figure out that there might be a problem with X11 configuration. is it possible? What can interfere my driver work in this conditions?
i use ubuntu 11.04 on virtual box. Thanks.

---

### Maybe this will help: in Xorg.0.log i see the following:

[    21.022] (II) No input driver/identifier specified (ignoring)

[   272.987] (II) config/udev: Adding input device  (/dev/input/event5)

[   272.987] (II) No input driver/identifier specified (ignoring)

[   666.521] (II) config/udev: Adding input device  (/dev/input/event5)

[   666.521] (II) No input driver/identifier specified (ignoring)

Answer (score -1):

By initialzing the name field of the device and enabling keybit events(BTN_MOUSE), i could get the mouse moving. Im still trying to find the reason why relative events are not working, without enabling key button events.

In the input device driver (i.e Virtual mouse driver init module function), i added the below lines of code just before registering the input device. Rest of the code is same as in the book

// Device name

vms_input_dev->name = "Virtual Mouse";

// Enable relative and Button events

set_bit(EV_REL, vms_input_dev->evbit);

set_bit(EV_KEY, vms_input_dev->evbit);

set_bit(BTN_LEFT, vms_input_dev->keybit);

set_bit(REL_X, vms_input_dev->relbit);

set_bit(REL_Y, vms_input_dev->relbit);

The code worked for me on ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I've seen this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17298688), but on both sides it is unknown what file should be changed or how to get it. Also there is no explanation what the code does or why it should be changed.

Comment: As i mentioned, the changes are to be done in the input device driver code, i.e in the Virtual mouse driver init module, just before registering the input device. The changes that i made, to the code in the book are, initialzing the name of the device and also enabling key events(BTN_MOUSE). Without these changes i couldnt get the mouse moving. Im still trying to find the reasons.

Comment: Could you please [edit your answer](http://askubuntu.com/posts/372852/edit) and add the information there? Thank you.